# How to create a rule on IPCop firewall for bittorrent trafic to work properly?

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, bittorrent, ipcop

I've been trying to use my favourite torrent client (µTorrent) after setting up my IPCop (last update 2.1.9) and it warned me that my router/firewall was blocking the traffic and that I had to open a certain port. I tried (on the IPCop) adding services, rules, port-forwarding, anything and nothing worked.

I need to know how to open ports for applications because I might be facing this problem again if I want to use some Steam games online for example.